# New Profile adding custom fields issue

Tags: contacts, custom-fields

I created a new Contact Type, Parish, based on Organization. No data added yet. I will display this as a  field in a Contact Records as a Parishoneer of relationship.

I am following a tutorial screencast of Roundearth CiviCRM Profile Forms. I wanted to create a Parish Sponsor Leads profile. I have First Name, Last Name, Email, Phone Number and Notes.

When I try to use Parish as a custom field, to be the first field in the form, in the new Parish Sponsor Leads profile I get this error:
Cannot add or update profile field type "Parish" with combination of "Individual".

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include a screenshot? You say that Parish is a Contact Type, but then you say it's a custom field. If we could see the screen where you're adding "Parish" it could help make it clearer.

Comment: It sounds to me like you are trying to use a Profile to create Relationships between the Parish and the Individual. I may be wrong. What CMS are you using?

Comment: I am using CiviCRM 4.7.30 with Drupal 7.57. I see a reserved Profile in CiviCRM New Individual that is a combination of Individual and Contact. I also see New Organization which is Organization and Contact. The new Profile would be New Parish, a combination of Parish and Contact.

Comment: so you are wanting Individual fields and sub-Organisation fields? If you are using Drupal i would switch to webform_civicrm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CiviCRM doesn't allow you to add contact fields or custom fields of different contact type or contact sub type. The processing of mix profile is still not handled in CiviCRM.

You can create custom field for individual and then use hook to create organization contact and relationships.

Comment: Should I also look into the code used for these examples?
New Individual is a combination of Individual and Contact. 
New Organization is a combination of Organization and Contact.

My new Profile would be New Parish, a combination of Parish and Contact.

Comment: First Name is not Contact, it is Individual. So am not sure your statement "a combination of Parish and Contact" is correct